# NestJS/swagger: what model is the ApiExtraModel expecting as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

The `@nestjs/swagger` doc describes [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#extra-models) that defining an extra model should be done this way:

```js
@ApiExtraModels(ExtraModel)
export class CreateCatDto {}
```

But what is `ExtraModel` here ? The doc is not very clear about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same uncertainity. 
After googling https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/355/files I understood the documentation:

- first import your model to be referred to by `import { ExtraModel } from '<filename>'` (<--- so this is lacking in the docs BTW)
- then provide it as param 'ExtraModel' to the decorator
- the decorator then decorates the class which refers to the model (so providing the reference)

I guess you had the same mind-twister as me that the `ApiExtraModels`-decorator acts on the model ...

Cheers,
Stephan

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me, when I've set @ApiExtraModels(MyModelClass) on the top of controller.

Thanks for this topic and also to [this comment](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/738#issuecomment-627812064) in GitHub issue.

I don't want to list all models in extraModels array in SwaggerModule.createDocument, so this is a great solution for me.